# Form field values missing after form submit

Tags: php, html

So I have a sample code working with forms, a simple php echo to make sure the form is posted correctly.
I'm using MDBootstrap for front end and am getting convinced there is a problem.

***Test Form***

```
<form action="../api/login/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="test">
    <input type="submit" value="test">
</form>
```

***Real Form***

```
<form class="col-6" action="../api/login/" method="post">
    <input required type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control form-control-lg">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input required type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control form-control lg">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-lg mb-2">
    <em class="dark-grey-text"><a href="../Register/">Don't have an account?</a></em>
</form>
```

***PHP echo produces***

```
var_dump($_POST["test"])
```

*Test*  or whatever was passed

```
var_dump($_POST["username"])
```

*NULL*

I suppose my question, is the front end assistance by MDBootstrap messing with my $_POST[]?
This could also be because the input is not a direct child of the form, but I tested and it still didn't work.

Comment: I don't see input with name `username`, Do you see?

Comment: @u_mulder Yeah, I suppose it should be `var_dump($_POST["email"])`, maybe.

Comment: avoid relative path in action.  action="https://www.example.com/api/login". use like this.